# Volley static callback listeners context GCed

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, android-volley

After using [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) I found that there were many leaks in my app, most of them due to Volley's anonymous callback listeners. So I wrote a Util (below) class which uses static callbacks and `WeakReference` to keep reference to `Context` and an anonymous callback. But when I open the app for the first time, i.e. a cold start, the context is GCed soon after the request is made but during a warm start all works fine. Also this happens only for the first activity in the app.

Any alternative way of handling memory leaks with volley which works properly are also welcome.

```
public abstract class VUtil {

    public static final String TAG = VUtil.class.getSimpleName();

    public interface JsonCallback {
        void onSuccess(JSONObject response);
    }

    public interface StringCallback {
        void onSuccess(String response);
    }

    public interface ErrorCallback {
        void onError(VolleyError error);
    }

    public static class JsonResponseListener implements Response.Listener<JSONObject> {
        private final WeakReference<Context> mContextWeakReference;
        private final WeakReference<JsonCallback> mCallbackWeakReference;

        public JsonResponseListener(Context context, JsonCallback callback) {
            mContextWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(context);
            mCallbackWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(callback);
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
            Context context = mContextWeakReference.get();
            JsonCallback callback = mCallbackWeakReference.get();
            if (context != null && callback != null) {
                callback.onSuccess(jsonObject);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Context was GCed");
            }
        }
    }

    public static class StringResponseListener implements Response.Listener<String> {
        private final WeakReference<Context> mContextWeakReference;
        private final WeakReference<StringCallback> mCallbackWeakReference;

        public StringResponseListener(Context context, StringCallback callback) {
            mContextWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(context);
            mCallbackWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(callback);
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Context context = mContextWeakReference.get();
            StringCallback callback = mCallbackWeakReference.get();
            if (context != null && callback != null) {
                callback.onSuccess(response);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Context was GCed");
            }
        }
    }

    public static class ErrorListener implements Response.ErrorListener {

        private final WeakReference<Context> mContextWeakReference;
        private final WeakReference<ErrorCallback> mCallbackWeakReference;

        public ErrorListener(Context context, ErrorCallback callback) {
            mContextWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(context);
            mCallbackWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(callback);
        }

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Context context = mContextWeakReference.get();
            ErrorCallback callback = mCallbackWeakReference.get();
            if (context != null && callback != null) {
                callback.onError(error);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Context was GCed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Sourabh how you pass that class object in Stringrequest and from that response how you redirect that response to respective activity response

Comment: pass object as `MyClass.this`? And I didn't understand what you mean by `redirect that response to respective activity response`

Comment: from different activities i m making networking calls so whatever the response that t receive i have to redirect it to specific activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to *djodjo*'s answer which helped me to reach a solution

- Always use `addToRequestQueue(request, TAG)`. Here `TAG` bit is what we'll use to cancel requests when their Activity/Fragment/View or anything is GCed
- What i did is create a base activity and add all this request cancellation code in that activity. Here's what it looks like

  ```
  public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

      public final String tag;

      public BaseActivity() {
          super();
          tag = getClass().getSimpleName();
      }

      @Override
      protected void onDestroy() {
          App.getInstance().cancelRequests(tag);
          super.onDestroy();
      }

      protected <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> request) {
          App.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request, tag);
      }

  }
  ```

`cancelRequests` is just simple code

```
getRequestQueue().cancelAll(tag);
```

Extend your activities from this `BaseActivity` and use `addToRequestQueue` to make requests, which will get cancelled automatically when your activity is destroyed. Do similar thing for fragment / dialog / whatever else.

If you make requests from anywhere else which doesn't follow a life-cycle, make sure that it's not binding to any `Context` and you'll be fine.

Comment: @MidasLefko, I want to also add cancelAll in my volley request. Where exactly do I add "getRequestQueue().cancelAll(tag);", is it in the singleton pattern? activity lifecycle? I'm confused. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Add  it on your `Application` instance, and because its Application you can safely make it a singleton using static reference or a `WeakReference`

Answer (score 1):

GC depends on many many things that are happening. One possible cause for your case is that when you do your first request after a 'cold boot' you app must init various custom objects, fragments, activities, views caches etc. and thus needs memory before increases the heap and thus do a GC.

The solution I propose however is to change your architecture.

1) it seems that u keep ref to context but it is never used. just drop it

2) you have Volley callbacks which delegates to your custom callbacks which you need to pass anyway, why don't you simply use 1 set of callbacks which you pass to the respective requests.

3) you WeekRef your custom callbacks but u cannot do without them. Week Referencing is not the ultimate solution to memory leaks. you have to find out why the ref is still there when you don't need it.

so if you leak issue is in JsonCallback, StringCallback and ErrorCallback implementations just try to figure this out instead of making the chain longer and cutting it at the end.